# epubcheck with error

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, epub

Now I am trying to validate produced epub files with the programm `epubcheck`, which I installed correctly and already used successfully to other newly produced epub files with tex4ebook.

But now I got an error message (or 9 nearly identical ones) when validating a larger epub file (with toc and indexing).

The error message is in german an says:

```
filename.epub/pathnameli1.html(12,38): Validierungsfehler: Der Wert des Attributs "id" ist ungültig; es muss ein XML-Name ohne Doppelpunkte sein
```

Translated:

```
filename.epub/pathnameli1.html(12,38): validation error: the value of attribute "id" is not valid; it needs to be a XML-name without colon.
```

I got this for pathnameli3.html, pathnameli5.html,..., pathnameli17.html. As a whole "9 errors".

When I open pathnameli3.html I find the following line refering to "id":

```
...
 <h2 class='likechapterHead' id='1'><a id='x5-3000'></a></h2>
...
```

Concerning the filename.tex source it refers obviously to the first pages with toc. Up to now I could not reproduce the error in a MWE. Maybe someone can get some hints out of this. What might be wrong? How to validate the epub up to "0 error"?

**Edit 1**

I looked at the pathnameli1.html (which produces an error), pathnameli2.html (which does not produce an error).

I find that the odd numbers up to 17 produce 9 errors messages of the above kind. The even numbers (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16) are as follows:

2: `<h2 class='likechapterHead' id='vorwort'><a id='x3-2000'></a>Vorwort</h2>`

They even numbers represent the all the `\chapter*{}` commands of the document.tex

Then I looked at these `chapter` commands in the document.tex and found `\cleartooddpage` commands and thought that it has to do with the problem and changed it to `\clearpage`. But the errors remained.

I do not understand the odd numbers of the pathnameli1.html and so on. Where are they produced in the document.tex? But they do come eventually with tex4ebook?

The part of relevant document.tex is as follows:

```
\cleartooddpage
\chapter*{Vorwort}
\ifdefined\HCode
\else\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vorwort}
\fi
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{Vorwort}
```

**Edit 2 - Full example**

This is the full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex[intoc=false,columns=1,noautomatic,title=Alphabetisches Verzeichnis]
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Keyword}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\fancypagestyle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Inhaltsverzeichnis}}   
\fancypagestyle{Vorwort}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Vorwort}}
\fancypagestyle{Something}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape About Something}}
\fancypagestyle{AlphabetischesVerzeichnis}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Alphabetisches Verzeichnis}}   
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[2pc]%
{\addvspace{0.5pc}\normalsize\scshape}%
{\contentslabel{2pc}}%
{\contentslabel{2pc}}{, \thecontentspage}%
[]
\titlecontents{section}[2pc]%
{\addvspace{0.1pc}\small\rmfamily}%
{\contentslabel{2pc}}%
{\contentslabel{2pc}}{, \thecontentspage}%
[]
\usepackage[rm,sc,small,center]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\Huge\scshape}%
{}%
{0pt}{\filcenter}%
[]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
{\large\scshape}%
{\filcenter\normalsize\textbf{\thesection}}%
{0pt}{\filcenter}%
[]

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{empty}

\ifdefined\HCode
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Cover}
\coverimage[natwidth=\paperwidth,natheight=\paperheight]{Cover_Someimage.jpg}
\fi
\clearpage
\normalsize
... Some pages with empty pagestyle ...

\cleartooddpage
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HCode
\else
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\pagestyle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\fi
\clearpage
\endgroup

\cleartooddpage
\chapter*{Vorwort}
\ifdefined\HCode
\else\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vorwort}
\fi
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{Vorwort}
... Some Foreword ...

\cleartooddpage
\chapter*{About Something}
\ifdefined\HCode
\else\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{About Something}
\fi
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{Something}
\clearpage
\section{First}\index{First}
... Some first things...
\clearpage
\section{Second}\index{Second}
... Some second things....

\cleartooddpage
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\pagestyle{AlphabetischesVerzeichnis}
\label{AlphabetischesVerzeichnis}
\small
\renewcommand{\indexname}{\Large Alphabetisches Verzeichnis}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Alphabetisches Verzeichnis}
\printindex
\clearpage
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

It reproduces the error 3 times. And also with the odd numbers `pathnameli1.html` for 1, 3, 5.

Comment: One issue is that the `id` should not start with number. What is strange is that you don't have any text in the title. Maybe you produce this title with a custom macro that  tries to fix something else?

Comment: See Edit 1. I looked at the appropriate html files for the `pathnameli1.html` up to `pathnameli18.html` to understand where they come from in the `document.tex`.

Comment: When I combine this snippet, and preamble from your older questions, I don't get any error from `epubcheck`. Could you please try to make a full example that I could compile and reproduce the issue?

Comment: See Edit 2 with full example. It reproduces the error 3 times when running epubcheck.

Comment: In another, more complex sourcename.tex file, with indexing, pagenotes and bibliography, I got with epubcheck 126 errors, with lots identical to these in this question here. Maybe there is a good solution for it. I am on my limits, I do not know how to solve this and make a valid epub out of it. Thanks for caring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by `titlesec`, it inserts spurious empty chapter, which produces extra page. This  can be fixed using this file, `titlesec-hooks.4ht`:

```
% titlesec-hooks.4ht (2022-03-16-14:13), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-03-16-14:13}

\let\ttl:@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\let\ttl:@makeschapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\let\ttl:chapter\chapter
\let\ttl:section\section
\let\ttl:subsection\subsection
\let\ttl:subsubsection\subsubsection
\let\ttl:paragraph\paragraph
\let\ttl:subparagraph\subparagraph
\:AtEndOfPackage{
  \let\chapter\ttl:chapter
  \let\section\ttl:section
  \let\subsection\ttl:subsection
  \let\subsubsection\ttl:subsubsection
  \let\paragraph\ttl:paragraph
  \let\subparagraph\ttl:subparagraph
  \let\@makechapterhead\ttl:@makechapterhead
  \let\@makeschapterhead\ttl:@makeschapterhead
  \def\ttl@format@si#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{}
  \def\ttl@format@ii#1[#2]#3#4#5#6{
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \ttl@format@iii{#2}%
    }{%
      \ttl@format@iii{#2}[]}
  }
  \def\ttl@format@iii#1[#2]{}
}

\endinput
```

It cancels the redefinition of the `\@makeschapterhead` command, to prevent any stuff that `titlesec` does to it.

Comment: Again and again, thank you so much for your support. Where do I need to save this file? Somewhere in TeX Live? Or in the same folder as the `.tex` file to process? I do not yet understand quite the function of these `.4ht` files? Is there a central folder in the TeX Live installation for it? Or does is need lokal storage and usage of these files always?

Comment: @Thomkrates I've installed this in TeX4ht sources, so it should be in TeX Live 2023 soon. You can install your own `.4ht` files in `~/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/` directory

Comment: Thank you. I looked at this folder and found that `titelsec-hooks.4ht` is still there. But in the above full example still 3 errors of the above kind appear (`invalid "id"`). I also changed the font to `stix2` so to avoid the problem with `ebgaramond` on my system. But the errors while running `epubcheck` on the `.epub` remain. Is there something else to do that I might have missed?

Comment: @Thomkrates it will take few days before the update gets there. You can check the `titlesec-hooks.4ht` after you see `tex4ht` in the update log of `tlmgr`.

Comment: Yes, I was curious to know and ran `tlmgr update --list` where `tex4ht` appeared. Then I ran `tlmgr update tex4ht` and waited for processing, which occured without problems. Then I ran `tex4ebook` on the above MWE (with another font) and got an `.epub`file without an error. After that I ran `epubcheck` and: still got the 3 errors of above. Am I still too early for your update? Or is there another problem going on?

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, you are too early, it will take few days

Comment: I now have updated with `tlmgr update tex4ht` and do not get any `tex4ht` in `tlmgr update --list`, it does not appear anymore. So I think I am connected to the newest version of it. - But in my above MWE I still do get the `3 "id" messages and errors`, when running `epubcheck`.  I really would like to have an epub with 0 0 0 0 errors and messages with epubcheck. I already had other 2 epub files generated with `tex4ebook` which give me 0 0 0 0 errors and messages with `epubcheck`. What else could be the problem? And what the key to fix it?

Comment: @Thomkrates ah, I found there was another issue, see the updated code

Comment: Thank you, Michal, for your dedicated work. As with the other issues we had in the last 3 weeks, I just need to wait some days for the latest tex4ht update in `tlmgr update tex4ht`?

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, I've added all changes to TeX4ht sources (you can see all changes here: https://tug.org/tex4ht/changelog.html )